# Define vector in Excel using the extreme interval points and a step

Tags: excel, vector, plot

I want plot a function y=f(x) in excel and do some operations on it. The function is defined in an interval (x1,x2) with a defined step xs. Obviously I can define the vector x by hand, but I cannot manage to define it automatically, something like I do in Matlab using (x1:xs:x2). Is there any way to do that?